# Cannot run Selling Partner API operations through the Node.js client

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-selling-partner-api

I have the following snippet:

```
const SellingPartnerAPI = require('amazon-sp-api');

process.env.SELLING_PARTNER_APP_CLIENT_ID = "..."
process.env.SELLING_PARTNER_APP_CLIENT_SECRET = "..."
process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "..."
process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "..."
process.env.AWS_SELLING_PARTNER_ROLE = "SellingPartnerAPIRole"

const TOKEN = '...';

(async () => {
    try {
        let sellingPartner = new SellingPartnerAPI({
          region: "eu",
          refresh_token: TOKEN
        });
        let res = await sellingPartner.callAPI({
          operation:'getCompetitivePricing',
          endpoint:'productPricing'
        });
        console.log(res);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
    }
})()
```

This fails like this:

```
{ code: 'AccessDenied',
  message:
     'User: arn:aws:iam::7xxxx9:user/XXX is not authorized to 
     perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: SellingPartnerAPIRole',
  type: 'error' }
```

I do not understand why it is failing, because I simply followed the [official docs](https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/guides/en-US/developer-guide/SellingPartnerApiDeveloperGuide.md#step-2-create-an-iam-user) to create the IAM user, the IAM Policy, the IAM Role and then setup this Node.js script.

I want to get the metadata for a given ASIN, but for now it simply ends with `AccessDenied`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Feels like its related to step 5 (adding the sts policy). Can you post the policy used for that user in you post please?

Comment: @LRutten I will talk to the administrator to double-check that together, but we definitely did that from what I remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should probably be `arn:aws:iam::99999:role/role-name` if the iam user has sts policy.(not user ARN)

```
process.env.AWS_SELLING_PARTNER_ROLE = "arn:aws:iam::99999:role/role-name"
```